# Memory Limit Error during Clickhouse background merge after trying optimize final

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table `T1` with 3103 parts. Some of them are very small parts given that the table contains 10B rows

```sql
select count(rows) from system.parts where table = 'T1' having rows < 5000
```

~1000

by looking at the table `system.part_log` I can see that the merge operation is failing 10 times a second due to low memory:

```sql
select query_id, event_type, merge_reason, merge_algorithm, duration_ms, partition_id, part_type, length(merged_from),read_rows, read_bytes, peak_memory_usage,  error, exception from system.part_log where table like '%T1%' and event_type = 2 order by event_time desc limit 1 format JSONEachRow
```

```json
{"query_id":"","event_type":"MergeParts","merge_reason":"RegularMerge","merge_algorithm":"Horizontal","duration_ms":"20811","partition_id":"all","part_type":"Unknown","length(merged_from)":"3100","read_rows":"244214","read_bytes":"147272968","peak_memory_usage":"3033714012","error":241,"exception":"Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 7.81 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4196387 bytes), maximum: 7.81 GiB. OvercommitTracker decision: Memory overcommit isn't used. Waiting time or overcommit denominator are set to zero.: (while reading column clm_agent_id): (while reading from part \/usr\/local\/clickhouse\/data\/store\/9da\/9dadcfe1-7c14-405a-8194-9c0a2596a997\/all_754218_774876_86\/ from mark 0 with max_rows_to_read = 1024): While executing MergeTreeSequentialSource. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) (version 22.8.21.38 (official build))"}
```

It is trying to merge all since I run the optimize final query

```sql
optimize table T1 final
```

but it was causing a memory limit error. I tried to cancel the optimize query, but it is ignored by clickhouse. Therefore, I restarted the clickhouse-server process.

I don't see the optimize query in the `system.processes` table after the restart, but the merges are still failing.

What should I do to prevent clickhouse to try merging parts all at once so that there is no memory limit error ?

Comment: How much memory do you have?  It looks like you're trying to run ClickHouse with at least 10 billion rows on a machine with 8GB.  That's almost certainly not enough.

Comment: I got 16Gb for the container limit. This is the max on my platform. It was working very well

Comment: You might check the system.merges table to get an idea what it's trying to do.  Did you change any `merge_tree_settings` from the default value?

Comment: Here are some custom settings: ```xml <max_bytes_to_merge_at_max_space_in_pool>2147483648</max_bytes_to_merge_at_max_space_in_pool> ``` and for T1 ````sql parts_to_throw_insert = 3120, index_granularity = 8192, merge_max_block_size = 8192, number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_lower_max_size_of_merge = 4
```. The `system.merges` always displays the current merge of 3100 parts that is destined to fail in milliseconds ...

Comment: Apparently the merge you initialized with the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement cannot be canceled.  The recommended approach is to DETACH and ATTACH the affected partition which will clear the merge.

Comment: I tried that out but it restarts the optimize query right after I re attach the table

Comment: try to partitions one by one OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table PARTITION ... FINALE